# Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources,

Tags: android

I am developing small Android app
but I execute the code it showing something like this I didn't understand what is going on.Please help me

My gradle file like this
please help me to out of this problem

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chinni.swipetabs"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are building a debug application. If you choose to building a release application, sources will be different(encrypt).